# How do I remove Maps from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

The Maps feature on Facebook Timeline is nice, though recently I have established that I am location paranoid and wouldn't like people seeing all the places I have been to, so I want to disable and/or remove it entirely from view on my Timeline.

Facebook with Maps

[image: Maps Tile shown above in Timeline]

Facebook with no Maps

[image: Maps Tile removed]

As you can see from the first image, I have ~700 spots tagged as Places, ideally I don't want to delete this metadata, but if that's what it takes to remove Maps, sure I can take the sacrifice. At best I just want to disable the Maps tile, no need for people to map out where I am like Carmen Sandiego.

I don't see an option under Facebook Apps or within privacy settings to remove the Maps, so how can I can disable Maps from Facebook Timeline? Is it also possible to remove the Maps altogether?

Comment: You want just to hide the location or disable it entirely?

Comment: _If you've already turned your location services setting off, you can turn it back on by finding your phone's main settings menu and making sure location services are allowed for the app._ ([Source](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=275925085769221).) So you should go into the main phone settings and make sure they are **not** allowed.

Comment: Disable the location entirely

Comment: Then, that’s a “phone feature,” so disable it from Facebook’s phone settings. (I don’t know the exact steps, sorry.) As for showing the “historic” data on your timeline, I have no clue.

Comment: Check the second answer from [this](http://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=2453177) thread, maybe it will help you.

Comment: Yup, that works, it removes it from display

Comment: Ok, if that’s what you were looking for, I’ll post it as an answer, maybe it will help others too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to your Timeline
2. Click on **Activity Log**
   [image]
3. Click **All** at the top of the page
   [image]
4. Click on **Posts with Location**
   [image]
5. Hide from Timeline all that shows in the list

To hide the map from favorites:

1. Go to your Timeline
2. Click on the arrow at the end of the favorites row
   [image]
3. Hover over the Maps box
4. Click on the edit icon that appears in the upper-right corner of the box
   [image]
5. Click on **Remove from Favorites**
   [image]

[Source](http://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=2453177).

Comment: Could you add the part about removing the tile from favorites?

Comment: @phwd Part added.

Comment: I did the above it didn't work.

Comment: i could not get step 4 to work. the icon in the upper right hand corner never showed..

Comment: @mal, make sure you don’t skip step 2.