# How do I permanently remove Maps from Facebook? Have followed all guides

Tags: facebook

Okay I followed this guide: [How do I remove Maps from Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31223/how-do-i-remove-maps-from-facebook)

Unfortunately although it does indeed "hide" Places from your timeline it only does it "initially".  If you scroll down and click on "See More Recent Stories" then Viola, it all pops back up again for everyone to see!!!

Secondly it does succeed in removing it from Favourites however my query is this, how the HELL do you remove the Map/Places/Location function completely from your Facebook account?  I simply do not want it.  Even a switch to turn it off would be good.  All help appreciated

Comment: I suspect that the only way is to remove all location information, including location in any posts, current city, and home town.

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "Places" vs "Maps"?